# How to access URL and bookmark title in .URL files?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, url, favorites

I'm using .NET 2.0 Visual Studio 2005 C#.

The code below gets file name of the IE favorites (bookmark) from the directory that contains bookmarked .url files

Example

../users/favorites/blah.url

But what I really want is the bookmarked URL inside of that file.

When check the file property, in the web document tab, it shows filename and URL.

How can I access it from C#?

**CODE**

```
 //the code below just get String like "..../users/favorites/blah.url"
 //call the method with the folder path: 
 //GetFavoriteFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites));


private List<String> favFiles = new List<String>();

private void GetFavoriteFiles(String folder)
{
    String[] favs = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
    favFiles.AddRange(favs);
    String[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(folder);

    if(folders != null)
    {
       foreach(String s in folders)
       {
          GetFavoriteFiles(s);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I opened a `.url`  in Notepad++ and this is what I found. Note, this was generated in IE8.
[This page](http://www.cyanwerks.com/file-format-url.html#urlformat) has a detailed look into the format of the `.url` (internet shortcut) file.

```
[DEFAULT]
BASEURL=http://www.google.com.au/
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,2
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.google.com.au/
IDList=
IconFile=http://www.google.com.au/favicon.ico
IconIndex=1
```

You should be able to parse this easily using basic `StreamReader` IO.

Comment: Oh! thats what I should have done in the first place, thanks I will try that.

Comment: Note that this format is an implementation detail, and is not guaranteed to remain as it is. See my answer for the proper API to use for parsing internet shortcuts.

Answer (score 6):

The current format of a `.url` file is [not set in stone](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/234552-parsing-url-file) and could change in any OS update. The right way to parse these files is via the [CLSID_InternetShortcut COM coclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using `IUniformResourceLocator` and `IPropertyStorage`. I just added that capability to [TvGameLauncher](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tvgamelauncher/), you can take the code from the [InternetShortcut folder](http://sourceforge.net/p/tvgamelauncher/code/ci/master/tree/TvGameLauncher/TvGameLauncherGUI/Interop/InternetShortcut/) (Apache 2.0 License).

Sample usage:

```
var shortcut = new InternetShortcutManaged(@"MyShortcut.url");

Console.WriteLine("URL: " + shortcut.Url);
Console.WriteLine("Working dir: " + shortcut.WorkingDir);
Console.WriteLine("Icon file: " + shortcut.IconFile);
Console.WriteLine("Icon index: " + shortcut.IconIndex);
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + shortcut.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Description: " + shortcut.Description);
Console.WriteLine("Comment: " + shortcut.Comment);
```

Comment: If this answer had references to the namespaces and a bit more information as to what and why you used the code you did I would really like this answer.

Comment: @Chris I linked to the specific MSDN article detailing all the internet shortcut related COM information. I also explained why this method is preferred, namely that the current INI format is an implementation detail that can change at any point, rendering old parsing code useless. Finally I added a link to working open source code you can take and use as is with virtually no license limitations, and even supplied a small sample of exactly how to use it. What more could you possibly ask?